# Insulation foam

Tags: plumbing, insulation

[image]

Plumber suggested using foam in this bay (*with a water supply for a standing tub filler*) because it was better than batts of insulation in stopping cold air movement, hence preventing freezing.

I thought that blow in foam insulation  didn't have a high R value compared to fiberglass.  Unless he meant a foam similar to a Great Stuff formula.

What would you use?

Comment: Why not contact the plumber and ask him what type he was referring to.  Answers could be based on opinions.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the word foam I would imagine he means the stuff similar to great stuff which does have a higher R value. Is the pipe partially insulated? I'd be worried about the fact that its directly on the drywall that's next to the un-insulated area. The down side to the foam if something goes wrong you won't be able to get in.